# how to a match text given an input value and add indented lines

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following sample text file. I specify a input value that I want to search for, in this case the word "car", then I would like to add the matched line "this is a car" and all the lines below it that is indented with two spaces, to a list.

1. How do I search the text for ("this is a" + my input value)
2. How would I got about adding only the indented lines after making a match to the list?

This is a sample of what the text file would look like:

this is a car 
   it is red 
   it has big wheels 
   manual transmission

this is a dog 
   it is brown 
   and long fur

I am thinking it would look something like this in pseudo-code

```
def action(self, filename, input):

    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        text = f.readlines()

    output = []

    for lines in text:
        if ("this is a" + input) in lines:
            i = lines.strip()
            output.append(i)
            goto next line
            while there is a single space
            i = lines.strip()
            output.append(i)
```

Then if I do a print of output I should see the following:

this is a car 
   it is red 
   it has big wheels 
   manual transmission

Answer (score 0):

When you go through `for lines in text`, have a flag that says whether you're currently looking for the starting text (this is a car) or for the following text (lines beginning with spaces).

In pseudocode:

```
looking_for_indents = False

for line in text:
    if ("this is a " + input) in line:
        print line
        looking_for_indents = True
        continue

    if looking_for_indents:
        if line.startswith('  '):
            print line
        else
            # that's all of them, stop looking
            looking_for_indents = False
```

Side comments:

- `input` is a builtin function in Python; naming your argument 'input' is bad practise
- lines.strip() gets rid of start/end spaces, it can't help if you're looking for them
- `readlines()` returns a list of strings, `for` iterates string by string. `for lines in text` implies `lines` is plural but it's not.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I got the indent matching working now per your suggestion. But how would I write the code to search for ("this is a " + input)? Also what can I used instead of strip() that will maintain start/end spaces?

Comment: I got the code to search for the string + input, just a silly mistake. But looking forward if someone can tell me what to use instead of strip() that will maintain the start/end spaces

Comment: @mmxool what do you mean? what to use instead of strip ... to achieve what?